# Access Cassandra on Google Cloud - Kubernetes from local DataStax Studio

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cassandra

I've setup Cassandra cluster on Kubernetes on GCP. I can very well execute the `cqlsh` from my local machine, using the CLI. However, I've DataStax Studio installed in my machine and I wish to access the Cassandra database on GCP. I've tried port forwards and it does not allow me to connect to the Cassandra instance.

I would be grateful if anyone can suggest me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this other post can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575640/datastax-devcenter-fails-to-connect-to-the-remote-cassandra-database/20598599#20598599

*(sorry I do not have reputation enough to write a comment instead of an answer)*